# Argument list error C++/CLR

Tags: pointers, c++-cli, clr, sound-recognition

I am creating a sound recognition program and there is a syntax error I can't solve in C++ here it is:

```
sRecognize->SpeechRecognized += sRecognize_SpeechRecognized;
```

The error says:

> Error 1   error C3867: 'SoundRecognizer::MyForm::sRecognize_SpeechRecognized': function call missing argument list; use '&SoundRecognizer::MyForm::sRecognize_SpeechRecognized' to create a pointer to member d:\c++\studio\testing\soundrecognizer\soundrecognizer\MyForm.h  114 1   SoundRecognizer

The function `sRecognize_SpeechRecognized`:

```
private :  
void sRecognize_SpeechRecognized(Object^ sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs^e)
{                   
    if (e->Result->Text == "exit")
    {
        Application::Exit();
    }
    else
    {
        textBox1->Text = textBox1->Text + " " + e->Result->Text->ToString();
    }       
}
```

Comment: did you try to write as compiler says: &SoundRecognizer::MyForm::sRecognize_SpeechRecognized instead of sRecognize_SpeechRecognized ?

Comment: Yes I have, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try to use operator = instead of += ? What is SpeechRecognized?

Comment: That is C# syntax, you must use C++/CLI syntax.  Like the error message says.  Just press the Tab key to let the editor autocomplete the assignment to `sRecognize->SpeechRecognized += gcnew EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs^>(this, &MyForm::sRecognize_SpeechRecognized);`